# Font corruption in code-like windows (e.g., tortoisehg)

Tags: lubuntu, fonts

My probabem is best illustrated by a picture (screenshot from tortoisehg-3.7.3):

[image: font corruption]

As you can see, there are two problems:

1. The font of the changeset ID is corrupted
2. Most noticably, the font in the diff window is cut off at half of its height.

I have already tried rebuilding the font cache via

```
# service lightdm stop
# rm ~/.fontconfig/*
# rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
# sudo fc-cache -srv; fc-cache -rv
```

, but without any effect.

The problem also occurs in *some* (but not all) code samples on the web (rendered via chromium), so I suspect it's a Ubuntu problem. I haven't noticed it elsewhere yet..

### System Information

I'm on Lubuntu 16.04, but the problem exists since 15.04.

In case this matters, my graphics driver is `i915`:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0d26] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller [1558:7410]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

### EDIT: It's `Monaco`!

The "cut off" font in the lower part of the window seems to be `Monaco` and it's *always* broken. For example, in the font selection dialog:

[image: Monaco broken in font selection window]

Does this ring a bell? Is `Monaco` different from other fonts in some way?

Comment: When I have seen this before, someone solved it with the right graphic drivers. What is your graphic hardware?

Comment: FWIW, I found a workaround *for tortoisehg*, which is manually setting the fonts to something else (Using Source Code Pro now). This came surprising because tortoisehg *claims* it uses the default Monospace font, but it doesn't really, and you need to set the fonts to something else to see an effect. The menu option is File -> Settings -> Global Settings -> Fonts.